# Mysql function fails in Laravel tests

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpunit

I have a query below that retrieves groups from the database; it works fine except when I run it through pest php test case and hit the controller; the test fails and says `Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such function: YEAR`

Here is my sql query

```
 Group::query() 
    ->selectRaw("YEAR(groups.created_at) as year,
                 MONTH(groups.created_at) as month, 
                 DATE_FORMAT(groups.created_at, '%b') as short_month_format,
                 count('*') as count"
            )
            ->whereIn('id', $ids)
            ->get();
```

Here is my pest php test case

```
test('authenticated user with permission will see analytics page ',function(){
    $permission = 'permission';

    actingWithPermission($this->user, $permission)
    ->get($this->route)
    ->assertStatus(302)
    ->assertDontSee("Text not to see goes here", false)
    ;
});
```

How can I fix mysql error above?

Comment: `count('*')` is invalid, it should just be `count(*)` or select a column to count

Comment: This query is already working on normal environment and fails only on test case @aynber

Comment: The test might be using sqlite, which does not have a YEAR function, instead of mysql, which does. Check your configuration in phpunit.xml

Comment: Are you configured In phpunit.xml your database to mysql

Comment: Thank you very much. Mysql was not set up in my phpunit.xml file. @NuriddinRashidov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the above issue by changing `DB CONNECTION` in `phpunit.xml` from `sqlite`  to `mysql`.

In my phpunit.xml

```
          .........
        <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql"/> 
        <server name="DB_DATABASE" value="database-name"/>
             .........
```

Comment: You should not add a "testing" connection, because if `mysql` is using (for example) `strict` as `true`, but no one changed `testing.strict` to `true`, then you have different results... Use the SAME configuration, except `host` and `user` and `pass`...

Answer (score 0):

count('id') is wrong , use count('id') or other field .